chain activities based on start/end date
I have an Timeline model with start and end timestamps (and other details).
I would like to create a relationship so I can jump to the next/previous activity.
They are not added sequentially, so I can not rely on id.
E.g.
Timeline::query()
  ->where('type', $timelineType)
  ->with('previousTimeline')
  ->limit(5)
  ->orderByDesc('start')
  ->get()

So: eager load these details.
Was hoping to use hasOne()->ofMany() with custom closure, something like:
// app/Models/Timeline

public function previousTimeline(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(self::class, foreignKey:'id', localKey:'id')
        ->ofMany(['start' => 'max'],
            fn($q) => $q->where('start', '<', $parentStart) // how to refer to the "parent" timeline?
        );
}

But how to refer to the "parent" timeline in the ofMany() closure?
And/or it is possible to use id for both foreignKey and localKey?
Or: what is the recommended approach?

I would recommend adding a column: next, prev to your Timeline model. When adding an instannce of the timeline mode (when creating one), set the prev and next of the one created, and update the next of the prev, and prev of the next. Like a linked-list.
